# Heroku: How to run npm build on a python application in Heroku during deployment?

Tags: heroku, npm

I have a web application written with a Python/Django backend API, and a Vue.js frontend.

We serve the static file produced by Vue as static Django files. The frontend application is located within a separate folder in the Django project.

At the moment before each deployment I need to run `npm build` locally and deploy with the dist folder.

I have a small script for deployment:

```
cd ./vuejs-frontend
npm install
npm run build

git add --force dist/*
git commit -m "Add dist folder"

local_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
git push heroku ${local_branch}:master -f
git reset --hard HEAD~1

cd ..
```

I want to move move the `npm install` part to be executed during the deployment. I am trying to add this in the `release.sh` that heroku executes during each deployment. Basically I want this in my `release.sh`:

```
cd ./vuejs-frontend
npm install
npm run build
cd ..
```

The problem is that the `heroku/python` buildpack does not have node and npm. I tried adding the    `heroku/nodejs` along with the other buildbacks, but then Heroku complains during deployment, that it was not able to locate a node application:

```
remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
```

Is there anyway to get `npm` on Heroku?

Comment: I think this is relevant for you: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: @KiraLT the suggestion from that article was the last buildpack in the list, determines the application type. I added python last, but still got the same error.

Comment: The last buildpack will be used for primary language. So I think you should remove all node logic from python and move package.json to the root level. And then add 2 buildpacks to the config: python & node (node should be first). So it will run node buildpack, which will build only node. After that it will run python buildpack, which should build python. I never tried it, so I can't say if it will work.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that the heroku/python buildpack does not have node and
> npm. I tried adding the heroku/nodejs along with the other buildbacks,
> but then Heroku complains during deployment, that it was not able to
> locate a node application:
>
> ```
> remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
> remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
> ```

You need a `package.json` at the root level `./` of your git repo. You only have one at `./vuejs-frontend`.

Just copy the `package.json` from `./vuejs-frontend/package.json` and adjust the script in  `"build": "<command>"` to `cd ./vuejs-frontend && <command>`

---

Side note:
This may become useful. You can define some Heroku specific build steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-prebuild": "echo This runs before Heroku installs dependencies.",
  "heroku-postbuild": "echo This runs after Heroku installs dependencies, but before Heroku prunes and caches dependencies.",
  "heroku-cleanup": "echo This runs after Heroku prunes and caches dependencies."
}
```